# Unable to use PyCharm Remote development - installing IDE backend in server fails

Tags: pycharm, remote-access

I'm trying to connect my local PyCharm installation to a server so that I can code directly in the server. For this, I go to `File` > `Remote Development` > `connect via ssh` > select the appropriate connection > `check connection and continue` > enter the password > `Next` > select the project directory > `Download and start IDE`. It downloads the backend on the server but then fails with the following message

```
An error occurred while execution command: 'expand-archive --archive-path='/home/nagasn/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/86e6698dbdca2_pycharm-professional-2022.1.4/86e6698dbdca2_pycharm-professional-2022.1.4.tar.gz' --destination='/home/nagasn/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/86e6698dbdca2_pycharm-professional-2022.1.4/86e6698dbdca2_pycharm-professional-2022.1.4''
Exit code: null
```

On googling the error, I see that the command `expand-archive` is a powershell command, which I understand is for windows and does not work in ubuntu terminal. So, why is PyCharm trying to run a powershell command in ubuntu? How can I tell PyCharm to use the ubuntu terminal command `tar`?

I also tried manually unzipping the downloaded archive and restarting the process, but PyCharm again starts downloading the IDE zip file and fails with the exact same error.

[image]

Comment: For me, it sometimes hangs...